# How to consume this with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, emscripten, webpack-dev-server

How can I consume this repo in a webpack react app: https://github.com/chris-rudmin/Recorderjs

I got as far as creating a new lib and exporting the main file in es6 module style.

I build with webpack, but the issue happens when I try to use the package. I am able to use:

```
import Recorder from 'audio-recorder';
var recorder = new Recorder();
```

But once I try to encode it then uses a WebWorker, and as far as I can tell, this needs to be a path to a js file.

So the question is in two parts:

1. How should I setup webpack to handle a dependency like this?
2. During development, how can I have the webpack dev server, serve static files?

Ideally I would like to create modules for all parts of this lib and have it easily consumed in any project.

Lastly, the encoder for this project is compiled via emscripten and I'm not sure how to handle a file like this in webpack. Is it possible to pass it through without having webpack touch it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to setup the dependency for webpack is to use npm - which supports installing from github.

```
npm install https://github.com/chris-rudmin/Recorderjs
```

Then you can import the module by its name (defined in [package.json](https://github.com/chris-rudmin/Recorderjs/blob/master/package.json)):

```
import Recorder from 'opus-recorder';
var recorder = new Recorder();
```

The webpack.config.js should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./main.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "babel" }
        ]
    }
};
```

Don't forget to install `babel-loader` to enable ES6 modules imports.

Use [webpack's documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) to setup dev server.

You can tell webpack not to touch ["external"](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) modules.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The issue is that repo does not use modules, also there is the issue of WebWorkers. When it uses the new WebWorker('path/to/script') it is not found. This is the main reason I want to wrap the lib so that it can be consumed via npm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this npm module - https://www.npmjs.com/package/recorder-js which is an es6 compatible wrapper to be easily consumed via webpack.